# Ruby on rails javascript doesn't load properly (HTML5 template)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new in ruby, so please don't judge me too much :)

I was trying to make this template http://freebiesbug.com/code-stuff/sedna-one-page-website-template/ run on rails. And it went pretty well.

However, I have stuck on configuring javascript parameters (the way it loads on rails). I am not sure how to do that correctly. Things that slides in the template doesn't work for me, like apple images and slider of employees in the bottom...

I tried to include all file names in javascript.rb file and also I have used:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

but non of these worked.

Any ideas where I may made a gap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files end in .js, not .rb, so thats one problem.

The line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

tells rails to package and include the `application.js` file found at `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. Assuming your template has one associated javascript file, you can copy and paste the contents of that file into your `application.js` file (which may be the easiest solution). You can also add any javascript (or coffeescript) files to the `app/assets/javascripts` folder, and those files will be packaged and served up in the default configuration of rails.

Comment: yes, that's correct it is application.js. The template contains many sub folders. Maybe I should just put all the files into assets/javascripts folder, and skip having all the sub folders?